# meaning of continuum

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is an excerpt from a TIME article.

> Crowded, poorly ventilated indoor environments remain the riskiest
> places for COVID-19 transmission. It’s not impossible to get COVID-19
> outside, but you’re much safer outdoors than in. Still,
> Sickbert-Bennett says there are certain scenarios where it might make
> sense to wear a mask outside, such as in the stands at a sporting
> event or at a crowded concert. “We prefer to have rules of thumb,” she
> says, “**but it is always a continuum**.”

I wonder what the sentence in bold means in that context.

Comment: Sickbert-Bennett is showing off her wide vocabulary - but it's not particularly idiomatic in this exact context, where most people would more likely say *...but **there are always grey areas*** or similar. Also it's not *quite* right for her to be juxtaposing ***rules of thumb*** with the fact that in reality things aren't always "black and white", because "rules of thumb" specifically implies *rules that don't **always** apply*. What she should have said was *We prefer to have **clear-cut** rules* - which *can* be naturally contrasted with "grey areas" and "continuums".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that there is not a single dividing line between 'it's always necessary to wear a mask indoors' and 'it's always safe to leave your mask off out of doors'. There is a gradual difference between the most risky and the safest environments.